# How to join 2 columns from one mysql database with 4 columns in a different database

Tags: join

I have 2 mysql databases. (1) authorID, authorFirst, authorLast. (2) courseID, courseName, courseAuthor1, courseAuthor2, courseAuthor3, courseAuthor4. How to join 2 columns from authors database into one OR ALL 4 of the courseAuthor columns in the courses database?

authors

```
authorID | authorFirst | authorLast
1        |   firstA    |   lastA   
2        |   firstB    |   lastB 
3        |   firstC    |   lastC 
4        |   firstD    |   lastC
```

courses

```
courseID | courseName | courseAuthor1 | courseAuthor2 | courseAuthor3 | courseAuthor4
1        | course1    |      2        |     3         |    NULL       |     NULL
2        | course 2   |      1        |     4         |     3         |     NULL
3        | course 33  |      4        |     1         |     2         |     NULL
4        | course 4   |      3        |    NULL       |    NULL       |     NULL
```

I Want Results to look like this:

```
courseID | courseName | courseAuthor1 | courseAuthor2 | courseAuthor3 | courseAuthor4
1        | course1    | firstB LastB  | firstC LastC  |     NULL      |     NULL
2        | course 2   | firstA LastA  | firstD LastD  | firstC LastC  |     NULL
3        | course 33  | firstD LastD  | firstA LastA  | firstB LastB  |     NULL
4        | course 4   | firstC LastC  |    NULL       |    NULL       |     NULL
```

I don't even know where to start. Here is my code:

> SELECT * FROM courses JOIN authors ON authors.authorID IN
>   (courses.courseAuthor1, courses.courseAuthor2, courses.courseAuthor3,
>   courses.courseAuthor4)

Which shows:

```
results  |  courseID | courseName | courseAuthor1 | courseAuthor2 | courseAuthor3 | courseAuthor4  |  authorID  |  authorFirst  |  authorLast
1        |    1      | course1    |      2        |     3         |    NULL       |     NULL       |      2     |     firstB    |  lastB
2        |    1      | course1    |      2        |     3         |    NULL       |     NULL       |      3     |     firstC    |  lastC
3        |    2      | course 2   |      1        |     4         |     3         |     NULL       |      1     |     firstA    |  lastA
4        |    2      | course 2   |      1        |     4         |     3         |     NULL       |      4     |     firstD    |  lastD
5        |    2      | course 2   |      1        |     4         |     3         |     NULL       |      3     |     firstC    |  lastC
6        |    3      | course 33  |      4        |     1         |     2         |     NULL       |      4     |     firstD    |  lastD
7        |    3      | course 33  |      4        |     1         |     2         |     NULL       |      1     |     firstA    |  lastA
8        |    3      | course 33  |      4        |     1         |     2         |     NULL       |      2     |     firstB    |  lastB
9        |    4      | course 4   |      3        |    NULL       |    NULL       |     NULL       |      3     |     firstC    |  lastC
```

Thanks So Much!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but i've answered my question. Here it is:

```
SELECT c1.courseID, c1.courseName, 
CONCAT(a1.authorFirst,' ',a1.authorLast) AS aOne, 
CONCAT(a2.authorFirst,' ',a2.authorLast) AS aTwo, 
CONCAT(a3.authorFirst,' ',a3.authorLast) AS aThree, 
CONCAT(a4.authorFirst,' ',a4.authorLast) AS aFour 
FROM courses c1 
LEFT JOIN authors a1 ON c1.courseAuthor1 = a1.authorID 
LEFT JOIN authors a2 ON c1.courseAuthor2 = a2.authorID 
LEFT JOIN authors a3 ON c1.courseAuthor3 = a3.authorID 
LEFT JOIN authors a4 ON c1.courseAuthor4 = a4.authorID
```